# Is there a site for game console topics?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to ask something about my Xbox 360. It fails to sync with my HD monitor, thus, it's not HD. But I cannot find any site that has to do with this kind of console, unless I can't see it?

Comment: What's the nature of your question about the console?

Comment: Its about how my xbox 360 fails to sync with my hd monitor, thus, it's not hd

Comment: @Vengeance: That's important information to include in your question, and comments are temporary. Please [edit].

Answer (score 10):

According to [*What topics can I ask about here?* on Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (gaming.stackexchange.com), you can ask *certain questions* about consoles there:

> Arqade is for passionate videogamers from **all platforms, including
>   consoles**, computers, handhelds, and mobile devices.

Those "certain questions" are *mostly* about the games themselves:

> If your question generally covers things such as …
>
> - Gameplay strategies and tactics
> - Puzzle solving or obstacle clearing
> - Game mechanics and terminology
> - Plot and characters in games
> - Game-specific hardware and utilities
>
> …then you are in the right place to ask your question!

If your question doesn't fall directly under one of those categories, be sure to follow the above link and read the article completely. Since you're asking a hardware question here's [a statement from an Arqade moderator](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6954) that seems relevant:

> The consensus, historically, is that hardware, and yes, even limited
>   hardware repair questions, are acceptable here. I'm not personally
>   terribly fond of them, for a host of reasons, much as I'm not fond of
>   tech support questions in general, but I understand that I'm in the
>   minority in that respect, and I don't vote to close questions on those
>   grounds.

If the problem is due to some specific behavior of the Xbox, then a gaming community seems like a good place to ask. On the other hand, if the problem is really with the monitor and has nothing to do with the console, it may not be very well received. Unfortunately for you, it's difficult to say which is the case until you know the answer!

I do not recommend posting this on Super User, at least not initially. A Super User moderator's answer to [Are questions related to repairing a console on-topic?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/2742/374604) is pretty clear:

> Console questions are off-topic

Try Arqade first, making sure to provide plenty of detail about how you're trying to set up the console with the monitor. If they determine that it's not about the console after all, then you can see about *possibly* getting it migrated to a more appropriate site.

Comment: And regardless of where you ask it, *include every single step you took to resolve it on your own*.  Tech support questions are best-received when you can provide as many details as you can on how you've produced the problem, and steps you've already taken to try to fix it.